# PayPal Chained payments failing

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm trying to get PayPal's chained payments working in their sandbox env. but whenever I click on "Pay" at the very last stage after signing in I always get redirected to a page with the generic error message "Your payment can't be completed. Please return to the participating website and try again."

I've tried doing both chained and parallel payments with the same results.
I've also followed a few suggestions from around the web which inc tweaking the merchant account settings making sure certain fields were unchecked under the "blocked" options. As well checking currency and country code. Initially country code was en_GB and currency GBP, that didn't work I tried doing en_US with USD but in all cases I get the same message.

I've also tried adding an IPN url on the off chance PayPal would post some error code/message to it but got nadda! If you click "Return to test store" it goes to the cancel URL without any POST/GET parameters.

I'm using their PHP SDK from http://paypal.github.io/#adaptive-payments-tab-php-5-3

[image: screenshot of error page]

[image: screenshot of what may be a relevant piece of info from the paypal error page]

So the question, does anyone have any suggestion as to how I can find out what exactly is going wrong or other things I can try to fix it?

Comment: Anyone else experiencing this problem, see my answer on [Chained payment cannot be completed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26984099/3917091). I'm hesitant to flag any of these questions as duplicates because people find different reasons for the cause of this very vague answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in the sandbox environment because I was not including an application ID. I used `APP-80W284485P519543T` which one of examples indicated as *the* Sandbox Application ID, and then it worked.

Comment: I'm having the same problem too, and I tried this but it didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

```
    Mobile Payments Library Developer Guide and Reference 
    –
    Android OS
Edition
Oct 2016
5
Preface
**Important:
The Mobile Payments Library is based on the PayPal Adaptive Payments API. 
As of October 6, 2016, Adaptive Payments is now a limited releas
e product. It is restricted to 
select partners for approved use cases and should not be used for new integrations without guidance from PayPal**  

     =============================================

      first implement method
           private void initLibrary() {
                PayPal pp = PayPal.getInstance();
                if(pp == null) {
                    pp = PayPal.initWithAppID(this, PAYPAL_APP_ID, PayPal.ENV_SANDBOX);
                    pp.setLanguage("en_US"); // Sets the language for the library.
                    pp.setFeesPayer(PayPal.FEEPAYER_EACHRECEIVER);
        //            pp.setShippingEnabled(true);
                    pp.setDynamicAmountCalculationEnabled(false);
                }
            }    


        **paypal button click event code**

             double secondary_payment = 0;
            double primary_payment = 0;

              PayPalAdvancedPayment advPayment = makeChainedPayment(secondary_payment,primary_payment,"primary_email","secondary_email");

              Intent checkoutIntent = PayPal.getInstance().checkout(advPayment, your_current_activity);
                            startActivityForResult(checkoutIntent, 1); 

            =============================================
            private PayPalAdvancedPayment makeChainedPayment(double priceSecondary, double pricePrimary, String primary_email, String secondary_email) {
                    PayPalAdvancedPayment payment = new PayPalAdvancedPayment();
                    payment.setCurrencyType("USD");
            //        payment.setMerchantName("PushND");
                    BigDecimal bigDecimalPrimary=new BigDecimal(pricePrimary);
                    PayPalReceiverDetails receiverPrimary = new PayPalReceiverDetails();
                    receiverPrimary.setRecipient(primary_email);
                    //receiverPrimary.setRecipient("adaptive_receiver_1@pushnd.com");
                    receiverPrimary.setSubtotal(bigDecimalPrimary);
                    receiverPrimary.setIsPrimary(true);
                    payment.getReceivers().add(receiverPrimary);

                    PayPalReceiverDetails receiverSecondary= new PayPalReceiverDetails();
                    receiverSecondary.setRecipient(secondary_email);
                    BigDecimal bigDecimalSecond=new BigDecimal(priceSecondary);
                    receiverSecondary.setSubtotal(bigDecimalSecond);
                    payment.getReceivers().add(receiverSecondary);

                    return payment;
                }
```

Comment: above code is working...
use this key - APP-80W284485P519543T